# Always finish Mono.usingWhen on cancel signal

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

we write a reactive WebFlux application that basically gets a resource, does amount of work in closure and at the end unlocks the resource with either initial version or updated one from closure.

Ex:

```
Mono<ProductLock> lock = service.lock()

Mono.usingWhen(lock,
            (ProductLock state) -> service.doLongOperationAsync(state),
            (ProductLock state) -> service.unlock(state))
```

`ProductLock` is a definition of locked product meaning that we can do operations via HTTP API including multiple microservices.

`service.doLongOperationAsync()` - calls a few HTTP APIs which ARE EXPECTED to ALWAYS be finished once started (failure - is normal, but if operation started - it needs to be finished, because HTTP call cannot be rolled back)

`service.unlock()` - operation MUST be called only after successful or failed execution of doLongOperationAsync.

In happy scenarios everything works as expected: on success product unlocked, on failure also unlocked.

The problems come when client, who calls our service (SOAP UI, POSTMAN, any real client), drops connection or times out - the cancel signal is generated and getting up till the above code.
At this point, anything within `service.doLongOperationAsync` is stopped and `service.unlock` is called on cancel asynchronously.

Question: how can we prevent this from happening.
The requirements are:

1. once `doLongOperationAsync` started - it must finish
2. `service.unlock(state)` - must be called ONLY after `doLongOperationAsync`, even on cancel.

[Spring Boot repro](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgWtih1nTVQYpL9KrotUjnz_ULXvnw?e=iURkJa)

MRE:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
    return RouterFunctions.route().GET("/work", request -> processRequest()
        .flatMap(res -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(res))).build();
}

private Mono<String> processRequest() {
    //Need unlock to execute exactly after doWorkAsync in any case
    return Mono.usingWhen(lock(), this::doWorkAsync, this::unlock)
        .doOnNext((id) -> System.out.println("Request processed:" + id))
        .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("Request cancelled"));
}

private Mono<UUID> lock() {
    return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(UUID.randomUUID())
        .doOnNext(id -> System.out.println("Locked:" + id)));
}

//Need this to finish no matter what
private Mono<String> doWorkAsync(UUID lockID) {
    return Mono.just(lockID).map(UUID::toString)
        .doOnNext(id -> System.out.println("Start working on:" + lockID))
        .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .doOnNext(id -> System.out.println("Finished work on:" + id))
        // Should never be called
        .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("Processing cancelled:" + lockID));
}

private Mono<Void> unlock(UUID lockID) {
    return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> System.out.println("Unlocking:" + lockID));
}
```

Comment: did you try `then()`? like: `Mono.usingWhen(lock, (ProductLock state) -> service.doLongOperationAsync(state)).then(service.unlock(state))`.

Comment: `then()` unfortunately won't do because we need the response from `doLongOperationAsync` and mono of corresponding type. `then` will change the flow. Also, it doesn't have `ProductLock` at that moment, so I won't be able to call `unlock(state)`

Comment: then can we just do this:
`Mono.usingWhen(lock,
            (ProductLock state) -> service.doLongOperationAsync(state).flatMap(failedOrSuccessResponse -> service.unlock(state).thenReturn(failedOrSuccessResponse)))`

Comment: It cancels `doLongOperationAsync` anyway and nothing is called afterwards. That's basically my problem, when client unsubscribes from server - server stops processing

Comment: the way is you have to the processing in new thread rather than request thread. try to implement the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833795/is-there-any-same-php-function-of-ignore-user-abort-in-jsp in webflux. it will done the tricks I think. Current request will block until it's finished. If client aborts request, the task will still run in background until it's finished.

Comment: Show MRE for `lock()`,`doLongOperationAsync()` and `unlock()`

Comment: What does MRE stand for?

Comment: Minimal reproducible example, basically just most minimal working example of what those methods do.

Comment: give us an MRE otherwise we will be suggestion and you will go no, no, no, no all night long. No one wants to spend time trying to solve this if there is no MRE.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf added mre

Comment: Stick your async function in a @Async annotated function

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thanks, but doesn't seem like it applicable here. From javadoc "n terms of target method signatures, any parameter types are supported. However, the return type is constrained to either void or Future." https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html

Comment: But why return something if the response doesnt matter? This all feels like very bad practice and poor design

Comment: What do you mean response doesn't matter? It's like "void" return type. I NEED save operation to finish and do commit/rollback. There's no response to care about other then the fact that update must finish. Are you saying living system in an inconsistent state is good design?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what does work for the usecase is using Mono/Flux create with sink. This way it's initiated when subscribed, but still not cancelled even when Cancellation requested:

```
Mono.create(sink -> {
   doWorkAsync().subscribe(sink::next, sink::error, null, sink.currentContext())
})
```

In case of using, whole `usingWhen` should be placed inside `create`